# magento2 images are not loaded in HTTPs

Tags: magento2

Cached images are not loaded in HTTPs

For example:

> mydomain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/182x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/n/o/non_deco_mix_plus_1_candle_best.jpg

It does not load under https while ssl is active in site

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the unsecure base URL

Navigate to **Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Base ULRs and Base URLs (secure)**.

Set you base URLs to go though `https://` protocol.

UPDATE:

You could also try this:

Navigate to **Content -> Design - > Configuration - > [yoursite] > HTML head - > Scripts and Style Sheets**

Insert this code:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

[image]

Comment: I have already set https base URLs

Comment: Did you do them for both? Secure and unsecure?

Comment: yes both I have done

Comment: Hymmm... try the above from my update :D

Comment: 404 error: Page not found.

Comment: error after adding the code

Comment: yourdomain.com works fine from me now ;) you need to redirect through https://

Comment: see the error on above crome you content not fully secure

Comment: Look at the image I added :P This is what you want isn't it?

Comment: which browser you have check

Comment: it not show on my side on chrome browser thanks

Comment: Sorry, was away yesterday... Did you manage to fix your problem? I think, you need to have a server side redirect through https://.